# GNU Radio with USRP

Tags: wifi, sdr

I have a problem transmitting a voice file from GNU radio to USRP. My problem is the simulation was working fine but when I transmit data from GNU radio attached with USRP to its receiver only noise is heard. Could anyone shed light upon it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guys over at the [GNURadio mailing list](http://gnuradio.4.n7.nabble.com/) are a great source of information for beginners, I've posted a number of messages over the last couple of months and always found the answer I was looking for (sometimes not directly though).